# The bounce effect in jquery is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, effect, bounce

I'm having trouble getting my bounce effect to work when I click on an image using JQuery. It just won't bounce. I've provided my code below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<a href="#"><img id="cog" src="images/icons/cog.png" alt="User Settings"/></a>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cog").click(function() {
        $(this).effect("bounce", {times: 3}, 500);
    });
});
```

Comment: what version of jquery are you running?

Comment: There is no "effect" function in standard jquery library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because it's part of the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) package.

Try adding this line

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for this! - I can accept an answer in 10 minutes. :\

Answer (score 2):

Effects are part of [jQueryUI](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Bounce), not jQuery.